# How can I test Java applet with different Java versions in Firefox?

Tags: java, firefox, applet

How can I test Java Applet application in the Firefox with different Java Plugins versions?
For instance, with Java 6 and Java 7?

Is there a way to guide Firefox to the correct java.plugin.dll?

Haven't found any Firefox command-line options with regard to NPAPI so far.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally, I managed to do this.

Steps to make your computer use another JRE/JDK:

1. Open `regedit`.
2. Open `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MozillaPlugins\@java.com/JavaPlugin,version=XXX` subtree.
3. Change `Path` value to the place, where your plugin dll is. E.g.: `c:\java\jdk1.6.0_37\jre\bin\plugin2\npjp2.dll`.
4. Change `Version` value E.g.: `1.6.0_37`.
5. Make sure, that you have correct Java in `%PATH%` environment variable.
6. In the Control Panel -> Java -> View disable all javas that you will not use. Select only the one you need.
7. Have fun!

Comment: This doesn't appear to work any more.  There is no @java.com tree.

Answer (score 3):

Deploy the applet using JNLP and specify the appropriate [`version` in the `j2se` element of the `resources` section](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html#resources).  That would be `1.6*` & `1.7*` respectively.  Note that will only work for 1.6 versions that implement the Plug-In 2 architecture JRE (e.g. Oracle's 1.6.0_10+).

See also [Java Web Start - Runtime Versioning](http://pscode.org/jws/version.html) for details on version string usage.

### Alternately

Go to the control panel and navigate to the JNLP Runtime Settings.

[image: JNLP Runtime Settings]

To test in 1.6, select the 1.6 JREs, and deselect the 1.7.